# Getting error "Cannot POST /contact error using express"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iD52t.png)I am trying to create a simple post request using express. I tried the code below for my form using pug.
When I try to submit my form, I am getting error:

```
extends base.pug

block scripts
  script(src='/static/app.js')

block style
    style
        include ../static/style.css
        include ../static/styleContact.css

block content 
    div.container
        h1 Contact Us
        form(action="/contact",method="post", class="myForm")
            input(type="text", class="myInput", name="name", placeholder="Enter your name") 
            input(type="phone", class="myInput", name="phone", placeholder="Enter your phone number") 
            input(type="email", class="myInput", name="email", placeholder="Enter your email id") 
            input(type="text", class="myInput", name="address", placeholder="Enter your address") 
            input(type="text", class="myInput", name="desc", placeholder="Enter your concern")
            button(class="btn")
                |   Submit
```

And here is my app.js code

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const mongoose= require("mongoose");
// const bodyparser= require("body-parser")
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/contactDance', {useNewUrlParser: false});
const port = 8000;


//Define Mongoose Schema
const contactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    phone: String,
    email: String,
    address: String,
    desc: String
  });
  const Contact = mongoose.model('Contact', contactSchema);

//EXPRESS SPECIFIC STUFF 
// app.use(express.static('static', options));
app.use('/static', express.static('static'));
app.use(express.urlencoded());

//PUG SPECIFIC STUFF
app.set('view engine','pug'); //Set the template engine as pug
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));  //Set the views directory

//ENDPOINTS
app.get('/', (req,res) =>{
    const params = { }
    res.status(200).render('home.pug', params);
});
app.get('/contact', (req,res) =>{
    const params = { }
    res.status(200).render('contact.pug', params);
});

app.post('/contact', (req,res) =>{
    var myData= new Contact(req.body);
    myData.save().then(()=> {
        res.send("This item has been saved to the database")
    }).catch(()=>{
        res.status(400).send("Item was not saved to the database")
    });
    // res.status(200).render('contact.pug');
});

//START THE SERVER
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`The application started successfully on port ${port}`);
});
```

Getting this error:

Cannot POST /contact

I keep getting the error "Cannot POST /contact" after submitting the form.

Comment: I assume you are recieving this error in the browser. what error code are you getting with the error (400?, 500?)

Comment: You should put forward the whole error stack, that way we could help better.

Comment: I am getting the error in the browser